# Notation for Lebesgue integration.

Tags: measure-theory, notation

I haven't seen this explicitly stated anywhere, so I just wanted to confirm my understanding of the standard notation for Lebesgue integration.

Say we have a measure space $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ and measurable function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued measurable function.
Is one of the below preferred over the other to denote the Lebesgue integral?

1. $\int_X f(x) d\mu(x)$
2. $\int_X f(x) \mu(dx)$

Comment: The notation varies, and it's really a personal preference of the author (and reader too). Personally I like 1. but others may disagree.

Comment: I've seen both, but I prefer 1

Comment: Ive seen both, and I ussually use the second because seems more natural to me, by example it can be used in differential geometry to represent measures on manifolds, and also in probability theory is more useful in general. The unique situation where I use the first one is when I dont want to explicit the dummy variable of integration, then I can write $\int f \,d \mu$