# measure theory notation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I've seen many equations for expectation using probability measures, some of that are using $\begin{align}\int f(x) dP(x).\end{align}$

And some of others are using $\begin{align} \int f(x) P(dx).\end{align}$

I think they are equivalent, right? Or what is the difference?

Comment: They are mathematically equivalent.  The different notations possibly give one a hint about the cultural or educational background of the author.

Comment: Similar question asked a few weeks ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394822/notation-for-lebesgue-integration

Comment: I see. thx all!